# How to run upgrade wizards from command line in TYPO3 8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

This works for TYPO3 9:

**Composer:**

```
./vendor/bin/typo3 upgrade:list -a

./vendor/bin/typo3 upgrade:run <wizardName>
```

**without Composer:**

Same as Composer, but use different path:

```
./typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 upgrade:list  

./typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 upgrade:run <wizardName>
```

As documented in [Installation & Upgrade Guide: Upgrade Wizard](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/master/Upgrade/UseTheUpgradeWizard/Index.html) (see also [Reference Index](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/master/Upgrade/UpdateReferenceIndex/Index.html) for both Composer and non-Composer)

In TYPO3 8, shows no commands "upgrade", e.g.

```
./vendor/bin/typo3
```

output:

```
 ... 
 referenceindex
   referenceindex:update     Update the reference index of TYPO3
 syslog
   syslog:list               Show entries from the sys_log database table of the last 24 hours.
```

How can you run these commands from CLI in TYPO3 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the binary `typo3cms`. 
The `typo3cms` binary is **NOT** part of the core. Its provided by the composer package `helhum/typo3-console` and includes the basic binary featurees plus some extra.

Call it like the `typo` binary => `./vendor/bin/typo3cms`
Then you will get the following output for the upgrade option:

```
upgrade
  upgrade:all                        Execute all upgrade wizards that are scheduled for execution
  upgrade:checkextensionconstraints  Check TYPO3 version constraints of extensions
  upgrade:list                       List upgrade wizards
  upgrade:wizard                     Execute a single upgrade wizard
```

TYPO3 also includes the binaries `fluid` and `doctrine-dbal` in the `vendor/bin`folder

Comment: I think typo3cms is supplied by the additional extension typo3_console, not the core.  Right? If you have to install an additional extension to execute update wizards - ok for me, but I think you should add that information to your answer.

Comment: @SybillePeters You are right. I will add the info now.